Why is Google Workspaces not setting DKIM keys for alias domains?
When sending email from our primary domain via Google Workspaces, Google fixes a proper set of DKIM keys in the header.
When sending email from our secondary domain, Google is inputting partial DKIM keys that do not validate when tested at DKIM Validator dot com. Also, if we send email from a Google Workspaces Account to another Google Workspaces account, we see that DMARC fails because of the malformed DKIM keys.
I've reached out to Google Workspaces support team. They say the system is working fine.  Even though, you can clearly look at the header for successful checks and failed checks and see that something is missing from the emails failing.
We've cycled keys for the secondary domain in an attempt to get DKIM to appear in those emails, no dice.
Not sure what we can do here. Any input would be valuable.
